# I can't figure out how to prove this using Index/Cartesian Tensor notation

Tags: calculus, vectors, proof-explanation

∇ ⋅ (**a** **b**) = a ⋅ ∇**b** + **b**(∇ ⋅ **a**)

Please note.....on the left side, that is NOT a dot product between vectors **a** and **b**. I'm assuming the problem wants them multiplied together to make a vector "a1b1, a2b2, a3b3".

I think you're supposed to use the product rule in this proof, but I'm not positive. If anybody can provide a step by step of how the heck you would prove this, that would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You want to prove $\partial_i (a_i b_j) = a_i\partial_i b_j +b_j \partial_i a_i$ (summation over the repeated index $i$ is implicit). So yes, you just need the product rule.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that $a $ is a vector field and $b$ is a scalar field. $\nabla \cdot (ab)$ stands for the divergence of the vector field $ab$.
$$
a = (a_1, \cdots, a_n), \quad ab = (b a_1, \cdots, b a_n)
$$

\begin{align*}
\nabla \cdot (ab)= & \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}(b a_1) + \cdots +\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}(b a_n) = \frac{\partial b }{\partial x_1} a_1 + b \frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x_1} + \cdots +\frac{\partial b }{\partial x_n} a_n + b \frac{\partial a_n}{\partial x_n} \\
=& (\frac{\partial b }{\partial x_1} a_1 + \cdots + \frac{\partial b }{\partial x_n} a_n)+( b \frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x_1} + \cdots  b \frac{\partial a_n}{\partial x_n})\\
=& a \cdot \nabla b + b (\nabla \cdot a)
\end{align*}

Comment: No, I checked that. The book definitely clarifies that both are vector fields

Comment: Can you post the complete text of the exercise? And what is the book? Unless there is a very good reason for using such a notation, I wouldn't trust it too much...